# Camel retry - large volume of retries slowing down the retry of individual transactions

Tags: apache-camel

We are using camel retry in our project. It works fine when number of transactions/period is low.

Our transaction are a ftp process - occassionally we encounter connections issues(servers are down etc) - so we have configured for a specific number of retry/delay - after which the flows goes to the error processor.

When there is a large number of transactions (say > 25) that fails and comes to retry loop all the same time - then the retry period of each transactions goes up...it takes more time for each of transactions to reach to the error processor.

We have configured a redeliveryprocessor to gather time statistics - as of now what we understand is that -

a) a transaction goes further and further back in the queue for retry each time other failed transactions are added to the queue.

b) the trigger for retry happens every second . We have added a scheduledexecutor service (10 threads to the deadletterChannel builder) - however the number of threads does not see increase the frequency of retry - since there are lots of transactions waiting for retry - expectation is there should be a retry happening as soon as transactions are available for retry and not necessarily every 1 sec.

Below is the blueprint snippet for this

```
<bean class='org.apache.camel.builder.DeadLetterChannelBuilder"      id="myDeadLetterErrorHandler'>
    <property name="deadLetterUri" value="direct:deadletter"/>
    <property name="redeliveryPolicy" ref="myRedeliveryPolicyConfig"/>
    <property name="executorServiceRef" value="redeliveryThreadPool"/>
    <property name="onRedelivery" ref="redelProcessor"/>  <!-- we have     used this for getting statistics of the retry --->
</bean>
<bean class="org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryPolicy" id="myRedeliveryPolicyConfig">
    <property name="maximumRedeliveries" value="${maximum.Redeliveries}"/>
    <property name="redeliveryDelay" value="${redelivery.Delay}"/>
    <property name="asyncDelayedRedelivery" value="true"/>
    <property name="maximumRedeliveryDelay" value="${maximum.RedeliveryDelay}"/>
    <property name="backOffMultiplier" value="0"/>
</bean>
<bean class="java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor" id="redeliveryThreadPool">
    <argument type="int" value="${int}"/>
    <property name="maximumPoolSize" value="${maximum.PoolSize}"/>
</bean
```

Need inputs/advise on how to limit retry delay when large volume of failed transactions within a short period

Comment: Mind about how thread-pools work in Java where they may only start to use more threads when the work queue is filled up. So it may be more desirable to not have a big work queue size. Also since your original input is from a file/ftp you may also consider a design where you just rollback and dont have in-memory scheduled retries in Camel, but instead just retry from the file/ftp again.

Comment: Thanks for your comment - sorry for the late reply. We did not want to use FTP retry as there was an issue that is now resolved via RH support - CAMEL-12850.  Currently we are planning to use a custom